# Can nginx cache OPTIOS request with ngx_http_fastcgi_module?

Tags: http, nginx, http-caching

We're seeing heavy load from CORS preflight requests which are OPTIONS requests. We already cache  HEAD and GET requests with the `ngx_http_fastcgi_module` nginx module.

But if we add `fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD OPTIONS;` nginx refuses to start

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid value "OPTIONS" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:120
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Doesn't nginx support caching OPTIONS requests?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe you could use [Access-Control-Max-Age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) header to cache preflight requests on a client-side?

Comment: No, nginx doesn’t support caching OPTIONS requests. Nor do any other servers that conform to the requirements in the HTTP spec. That’s because the HTTP spec explicitly defines most HTTP methods other than GET or HEAD as non-cacheable, including the OPTIONS method; see the last sentence of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.7, which says *“Responses to the OPTIONS method are not cacheable”*. So by disallowing OPTIONS caching, nginx is conforming to the requirements of the HTTP spec

Comment: Interesting. It seems nginx can cache POST requests but I guess it ok in some circumstances "Responses to POST requests are only cacheable when they include explicit freshness information" https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#page-26

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-max-age
it's OK to cache OPTIONS in client side using `Access-Control-Max-Age`.